# Is a declarative service a singleton by default?

Tags: osgi, equinox, declarative-services

The configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<scr:component xmlns:scr="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/scr/v1.1.0" enabled="true" immediate="true" name="printing">
   <implementation class="printing.PrinterManager"/>
   <service>
      <provide interface="service.printing.IPrinterManager"/>
   </service>
</scr:component>
```

The class:

```
public class PrinterManager implements IPrinterManager {

    public void activate(BundleContext ctx) {
        System.err.println("hello");
    }

    public void deactivate(BundleContext ctx) {
        System.err.println("bye");
    }
}
```

When I inject an object of that class somewhere else in my code like this:

```
@Inject
IPrinterManager pm;
```

Do I always get the same instance of that class or not?
How to make that instance a singleton with the help of osgi/equinox facilities if it's not a singleton already? (I know how to write a singleton the java/vanilla way, that's not my question)

Comment: @Inject? Shouldn't this be @Reference?

Comment: I guess it depends on the DI framework of your choice. @Inject is what works for me in an equinox/e4/javafx constellation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes a DS component is a singleton by default. See [Multiple Component Instances with OSGi Declarative Services](http://njbartlett.name/2010/07/19/factory-components-in-ds.html)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, would you mind to share a link to your source of knowledge?

Comment: Added the link to the answer